# display database value in modal frame only displays first record

Tags: mysql

in my database I have stored important dates. The database contains the following tables:

```
id (primary, AI)
Date
Title
Description
```

On the mainpage all the dates and titles are displayed. All titles contains a link which visitors can click to get more information. This information is stored in the "description" table. I want this info to be displayed in a modal frame. So I have this code:

```
$sql_data="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name_data ORDER BY date ASC";
$result_data=mysql_query($sql_data);
<?php
while($rows_data=mysql_fetch_array($result_data)){
?>
<a href='#' class='basic'>
<font>
<b><? echo $rows_data['Date']; ?></b> : 
<br />
<? echo $rows_data['Titel']; ?>
</font>
</a>
<br />
<div id="basic-modal-content">
<h3><? echo $rows_data['Titel']; ?></h3>
<p><? echo $rows_data['Description']; ?></p>
</div>
<?php
}
?>
```

Now this works partly as I want it to. It opens a modal frame, displays all the info from the table, but only for the first table. On the mainpage it displays all different dates and titles, but when I click one, it shows the data from the first record in the modal frame, regardless it's ID.

So if I click on the title with ID 2 it opens the modal frame with title id 1 and description id 1, if I click on the title with ID 74 it still opens the modal frame with title id 1 and description id 1.

How can I fix this code so it will display the values from it's corresponding ID?

Comment: How do you decide what ID you must show when link is clicked? I do not see any reference to record ID in your HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$sql_data="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name_data ORDER BY date ASC";
$result_data=mysql_query($sql_data);
<?php
while($rows_data=mysql_fetch_array($result_data)){
?>
<a href='#' class='basic' id="m_<?php echo $rows_data['id'];?>">
<font>
<b><? echo $rows_data['Date']; ?></b> : 
<br />
<? echo $rows_data['Titel']; ?>
</font>
</a>
<br />
<div id="basic-modal-content_<?php echo $rows_data['id'];?>">
<h3><? echo $rows_data['Titel']; ?></h3>
<p><? echo $rows_data['Description']; ?></p>
</div>
<?php
}
?>
```

Script

```
$(".basic").click(function(){
 var id = $(this).attr("id");
  var id1 = id.split("_");
   $("#"+id1[1]).modal('show');
});
```

Comment: thanks but now it displays the description directly right under the title on the mainpage. And when I click on the link, it opens an empty modal box

Comment: in the <a href> code you're creating an ID that starts with m_  but in the script I cannot find this m_ is this the why I don't see any records?

Comment: found the problem, $("#"+id1[1]).modal('show'); needs to be $("#basic-modal-content_"+id1[1]).modal('show');