# Displays only first title's info for all title on popup window

Tags: php, html, css

help needed...a simple page which display titles from db in descending order by date. All titles contains an image link which visitors can click to get more information for that title on popup window using HTML5 & CSS3. I am able to get only first title's info for all title. I've googled but did not get the answer. I've also found similar question & answer at stackoverflow [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21162883/display-database-value-in-modal-frame-only-displays-first-record)
But didn't help! Below is the code...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/modal.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body id="index" class="home">
<section id="wtsnew">
    <h2>What's new?</h2>
</section>
<section class="wtsnew_vs" id="ex3">
    <?php
        include 'dbconn.php';
        $query = "SELECT * FROM wts_new ORDER BY wn_date DESC";
        $result = mysql_query($query,$con);
        $today = date("Y-m-d");
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
        {
            $wn_date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($row['wn_date']));
            $wn_date_a = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($row['wn_date']."+1 day"));
            if($wn_date >= $today){
                $wtsnew = "<section id=\"wtsnew\">
                    <h3>Today</h3>
                </section>";
                $wn_date_c = date("d-m-Y - g:i a ", strtotime($row['wn_date']));
            }else if($wn_date_a >= $today){
                $wtsnew = "<section id=\"wtsnew\">
                    <h3>Yesterday</h3>
                </section>";
                $wn_date_c = date("d-m-Y - g:i a ", strtotime($row['wn_date']));
            }else{
                $wtsnew = "<section id=\"wtsnew\">
                    <h3>Old</h3>
                </section>";
                $wn_date_c = date("d-m-Y - g:i a ", strtotime($row['wn_date']));
            }
    ?>
 <section id="content" class="body">
    <ol id="posts-list" class="hfeed">
        <li><article class="hentry">    
            <header>
                <?php echo $wtsnew; ?>
                <h2 class="entry-title"><a rel="bookmark" title="Go in detailed!" href="#"><?php echo $row['wn_title'];?></a></h2>
            </header>

    <a href="#x" class="overlay" id="detail_display"></a>
        <div class="popup" style="color:black">
            <?php echo $row['wn_detail'];?>
            <a class="close" href="#close"></a>
        </div>
            <footer class="post-info">
                <abbr class="published">
                    <?php 
                        echo $wn_date_c;
                    ?>
                </abbr>
                <address class="vcard author">
                    By <a class="url fn" href="#"><?php echo $row['wn_by'];?></a>
                </address>
            </footer><!-- /.post-info -->
        </article></li>
    </ol><!-- /#posts-list -->
    <a href="#detail_display"><img src="images/expand.jpg"/></a>
</section><!-- /#content -->
<?php } ?>
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

Whenever I click on `<a href="#detail_display"><img src="images/expand.jpg"/></a>` popup is displaying details of first title only even if we click on 2nd, 3rd or even 22nd title.

Could some one help me out to show info of corresponding title on popup window (or modal) whenever clicked on image link?

Comment: html ids should be unique, append the db row id to all the ids in the while loop

Comment: Also *Obligatory Suggestion*, [**Don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: PDO...that was helpful. Can you please post any code for my current requirement?

Comment: My requirement is exactly like [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17439354/passing-php-variable-to-modal-window-with-click-function) here. I am new to this so can some one plz send complete code as an example for this problem?

Comment: I already said, **html ids must be unique**, so change all the `id=\"wtsnew\"` within the loop to `id=\"wtsnew_{$row['id']}\"`, **make them unique**.

Answer (score 0):

[HTML ids must be unique](http://webdesign.about.com/od/css/f/blfaqmultiIDs.htm), an easy route is to append the row id or iteration integer to the end of the id E.G: `id=\"wtsnew_{$row['id']}\"`, if it causes problems with your CSS then it should not be an id but a class instead.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/modal.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body id="index" class="home">
<section id="wtsnew">
    <h2>What's new?</h2>
</section>
<section class="wtsnew_vs" id="ex3">
    <?php
    include 'dbconn.php';
    $query = "SELECT * FROM wts_new ORDER BY wn_date DESC";
    $result = mysql_query($query,$con);
    $today = date("Y-m-d");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        $wn_date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($row['wn_date']));
        $wn_date_a = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($row['wn_date']."+1 day"));
        if($wn_date >= $today){
            $wtsnew = "<section id=\"wtsnew_{$row['id']}\">
                    <h3>Today</h3>
                </section>";
            $wn_date_c = date("d-m-Y - g:i a ", strtotime($row['wn_date']));
        }else if($wn_date_a >= $today){
            $wtsnew = "<section id=\"wtsnew_{$row['id']}\">
                    <h3>Yesterday</h3>
                </section>";
            $wn_date_c = date("d-m-Y - g:i a ", strtotime($row['wn_date']));
        }else{
            $wtsnew = "<section id=\"wtsnew_{$row['id']}\">
                    <h3>Old</h3>
                </section>";
            $wn_date_c = date("d-m-Y - g:i a ", strtotime($row['wn_date']));
        }
    ?>
 <section id="content_<?php echo $row['id']?>" class="body">
    <ol id="posts-list_<?php echo $row['id']?>" class="hfeed">
        <li><article class="hentry">    
            <header>
                <?php echo $wtsnew; ?>
                <h2 class="entry-title"><a rel="bookmark" title="Go in detailed!" href="#"><?php echo $row['wn_title'];?></a></h2>
            </header>

    <a href="#x" class="overlay" id="detail_display_<?php echo $row['id']?>"></a>
        <div class="popup" style="color:black">
            <?php echo $row['wn_detail'];?>
            <a class="close" href="#close"></a>
        </div>
            <footer class="post-info">
                <abbr class="published">
                    <?php 
                    echo $wn_date_c;
                    ?>
                </abbr>
                <address class="vcard author">
                    By <a class="url fn" href="#"><?php echo $row['wn_by'];?></a>
                </address>
            </footer><!-- /.post-info -->
        </article></li>
    </ol><!-- /#posts-list -->
    <a href="#detail_display_<?php echo $row['id']?>"><img src="images/expand.jpg"/></a>
</section><!-- /#content -->
<?php } ?>
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Much like how this site uses `#23340679` to this post/answer on the same page as other answers(though there are none...yet), the `23340679` is most likely the row id of this answer. The source looks like `<div id="answer-23340679" class="answer" data-answerid="1" >` if all answers were `<div id="answer-1" class="answer" data-answerid="1">` how would the javascript/DOM/hashtag ect reference this particular post.

Comment: You are lifesaver Loz...I really stuck & frustrated for this problem but thanks to you. Now realize I seriously have to take a quick tour of these new things. I m currently on this urgent requirement but defiantly I’ll have a tour later. Loz u r right, I m having prob wd my CSS. Does `“E.G: id=\"wtsnew_{$row['id']}\", if it causes problems with your CSS then it should not be an id but a class instead”` means do I need to change my id’s to classes in .css file? I m using Google downloaded CSS in my code for modal. Please help.

Comment: Can you please clarify on above pt Loz?

Comment: so whats the problem, yes change your id’s to classes in .css file if you use a properties multiple times on the page. **HTML ids must be unique** there is no work-around.